# Get original Regex pattern for which match is found

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Consider I have : `Match regexMatch = regex.Match(lineToScan);`
regex is an object of `Regex` conataining regex pattern (eg A|B|C)
So can i find for which regex (either for A or for B etc.) the mach is found?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) as this will return all matches in a collection.

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(value, pattern))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups to determine which part of the regular expression that matches:

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<a>A)|(?<b>B)|(?<c>C)");
var match = regex.Match("B");
var matchesA = match.Groups["a"].Success; // will be false
var matchesB = match.Groups["b"].Success; // will be true
var matchesC = match.Groups["c"].Success; // will be false
```

Each part is given a name ('a', 'b' and 'c') by using a named group. You can then examine the `Groups` property to discover which group (if any) has a successful match.

Comment: Sounds like ok, but the only problem is i am forming the regex pattern dynamically.. So cant use the Named collection for group capturing. Is there any way to get it from Match object?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with words you need 2 Matches:

```
string regex_string = "WORD_0|WORD_1|WORD_N";
Regex regex_matcher = new Regex(@"(" + regex_string + @")\b", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string result = regex_matcher.Replace("This return 'word_1' in UpperCase", m => Regex.Match(regex_string, m.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline).Value);
```